# how can i write a driver without any library or frame work?

Tags: c++, c, driver

my question is "How to write a driver without WDK or DDK or ...?"
I googled it but i couldn't find any thing...
and i just want to do it for educational purpose 
and i want to do it in windows 7 
and i know c and assembly (but not pro in assembly)

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: No, you don't need to apologize for your bad English. You just need to write questions that make sense, provide the necessary information, and can be answered without having to write an entire textbook.

Comment: You can't do it (at least reasonably at all) without something like the DDK, which (among other things) includes the headers that declare the functions you need to use.

Comment: What kind of driver? Most types of device driver will require you to write kernel code. Doing so on Windows without a WDK/DDK isn't really going to work.

Comment: What OS are you designing a driver for? If it's for Windows, good luck without WDK/DDK. If it's for linux, you can just source-dive through existing code for examples. If you are coding on a Microchip PIC or Atmel AVR chip, you already have direct access to the i/o pins and can make your own low-level drivers directly in C or assembler.

Comment: Learning how to do something that nobody would **ever** do is not a good use of your time.  Writing a driver is hard enough with the driver dev kits, and of far more useful real world educational value to you.

Comment: my os is windows 7.and my cpu is intel core 2 due, so if there is no way how DDK do that?

Comment: er,,is there not a build utility in the [freely available WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11800) ? ~in any case if your *set on crafting your own build-system then `do{ ida.hex-rays(.sys, wdk, etc);}while(13);` ;) ~all is possible given enough time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Writing a driver for ANY operating system requires knowledge about the OS kernel's driver structures and system calls and other behavior: this is what the DDK provides for you. Attempting to do this WITHOUT the DDK would be the same as attempting to re-implement all the kernel's driver structures and system calls from scratch.

Conceivably this could be done: practically it is not really possible, particularly for any mature operating system such as Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant driver that enables system to use some hardware - it is (virtually) not possible. The driver must interface somehow with the system, and that's what DDK is for.

But if you just want to access some device you have (eg. connected via COM, LPT or USB), you don't need any drivers except those for COM, LPT or USB (already in the system).

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to do this without using the driver kits - Microsoft is **legally bound** by the US Government Dept. of Justice decrees from providing OS access to anybody (even their own devs) via privileged/non-published APIs.

Comment: these driver kits are wrote by some program language and by some programmers so there must be a way to accomplish this

Comment: To do this you need to get a job in the Windows kernel development team

Comment: i know there must be a way if you know how plz tell me its not important that it need how much skills i will try to learn any new thing that i don't know

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the WDK or DDK do and recreate it.  You'll be pushing special values into special registers, responding to special interrupts...etc.

LOT'S of work ahead for you.

Good luck!

Comment: i cant use interrupts because my program is running in ring3 and interrupts are forbidden (when i tried to do that  i got permission error xD) and to run my program in kernel mode my program must be driver (thats what i know maybe its wrong =) )

Answer (score 0):

If you mean driver as in a driver that works under a specific operating system such as Win7, then naturally you need a development kit such as WDK unless you want to re-invent the wheel.
It's like developing a game without using a framework, or developing Android Apps without using Android SDK. It's possible but a very very hard task which could be done easily using a development kit such as WDK.
EDIT: If you really want to go deep into the code that handles drivers, you can create a driver with DDK and then use reverse engineering to take a look at the code at low-level and see how it interacts with CPU for handling the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Windows internals but Andrew Tridgell did a talk on reverse engineering Windows drivers using LD_Preload. He didn't use any driver kits or the like

I also know nothing about the Window's dynamic linker (I'm pretty sure Windows doesn't use .so's) but his technique of running Windows through a virtual machine (he used virtual box) under Linux should work.

You can see more details here http://lwn.net/Articles/425714/

Reverse engineering an existing driver should give you a good start towards writing your own.